# Failed to bring machine into sleep via pm-suspend

Tags: suspend, power-management, mint

When execute `pm-suspend`, I got `I/O error`.

And after checking other similar posts, didn't found a solution that fix the issue.

### The OS on pc:

The pc has dual operating system:

- `win8.1`
- `mint mate 17.2` (*3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux*).

The `secure boot` is disabled, as well as win8's quick start.

### Behavior of `pm-suspend`:

The command try to sleep first, then the system wake up again 1 second later.

Sometimes after reboot `pm-suspend` could work, another reboot might cause it won't work again.

The key error tip from pm-suspend.log is:

```
Thu Sep 24 20:39:44 CST 2015: performing suspend
sh: echo: I/O error
Thu Sep 24 20:39:45 CST 2015: Awake.
```

I don't know how to check which part cause the `I/O error`.

---

### Config files

**/etc/fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=7bc2e50d-9e01-4d06-80de-ef99a77a9a9f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=974cbad7-2d40-49d1-b09f-be2c4102b7a5 /mnt/star       ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=ee407faa-1576-4695-9157-11fa0fd9d2ff none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=BAC0A2A2C0A2647B   /media/Eric       ntfs-3g iocharset=utf8,umask=000   0       0 
UUID=9E5045285045088B   /media/John       ntfs-3g iocharset=utf8,umask=000   0       0
```

---

### More logs

Following are the full logs generated during an attempt of `sudo pm-suspend`.

**pm-suspend.log**

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Thu Sep 24 20:39:43 CST 2015: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux eric-pc 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
hid_generic            12559  0 
usbhid                 52616  0 
ctr                    13049  2 
ccm                    17773  2 
rfcomm                 69509  8 
bnep                   19624  2 
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
uvcvideo               81073  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            15681  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              153793  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  21903  2 uvcvideo,videodev
arc4                   12608  2 
ip6t_REJECT            12939  1 
xt_hl                  12521  6 
ip6t_rt                13537  3 
nf_conntrack_ipv6      18894  8 
nf_defrag_ipv6         34768  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
ipt_REJECT             12541  1 
xt_LOG                 17718  10 
xt_limit               12711  13 
xt_tcpudp              12884  34 
xt_addrtype            12635  4 
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14806  8 
iwlmvm                217725  0 
nf_defrag_ipv4         12758  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
xt_conntrack           12760  16 
mac80211              652777  1 iwlmvm
ip6table_filter        12815  1 
ip6_tables             27026  1 ip6table_filter
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    12665  0 
nf_conntrack_broadcast    12589  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nf_nat_ftp             12770  0 
nf_nat                 22050  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack_ftp       18638  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack          105081  8 nf_nat_ftp,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_nat,xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6
iptable_filter         12810  1 
ip_tables              27240  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               34059  13 ip6table_filter,xt_hl,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,xt_limit,xt_conntrack,xt_LOG,iptable_filter,ip6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,ip6_tables,xt_addrtype,ip6t_REJECT
dell_led               12920  1 
dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
dcdbas                 14928  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47548  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    77467  1 
dm_multipath           22843  0 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69011  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
scsi_dh                14882  1 dm_multipath
intel_rapl             18783  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       18823  0 
coretemp               13441  0 
kvm_intel             143590  0 
kvm                   452088  1 kvm_intel
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0 
crc32_pclmul           13133  0 
snd_hda_intel          30469  5 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
snd_hda_controller     30228  1 snd_hda_intel
aesni_intel           152552  4 
snd_hda_codec         139682  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
iwlwifi               179412  1 iwlmvm
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
cfg80211              494362  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
joydev                 17393  0 
serio_raw              13483  0 
snd_pcm               104112  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
lpc_ich                21093  0 
snd_seq                63074  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29562  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
btusb                  32497  0 
bluetooth             446409  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
mei_me                 19696  0 
i2c_hid                18726  0 
hid                   110426  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
snd                    79468  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
mei                    87875  1 mei_me
soundcore              15047  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
int3403_thermal        12967  0 
dw_dmac                12835  0 
dw_dmac_core           28390  1 dw_dmac
i2c_designware_platform    12979  0 
i2c_designware_core    14768  1 i2c_designware_platform
shpchp                 37047  0 
acpi_pad               17942  0 
mac_hid                13227  0 
parport_pc             32741  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
dm_mirror              22135  0 
dm_region_hash         20862  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18411  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
nouveau              1206535  0 
i915                  906113  6 
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
ttm                    93588  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           13413  2 i915,nouveau
drm_kms_helper         61574  2 i915,nouveau
psmouse               106610  0 
ahci                   34062  5 
r8169                  71694  0 
drm                   311018  7 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
libahci                32424  1 ahci
mii                    13934  1 r8169
wmi                    19193  4 dell_led,dell_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  20128  2 i915,nouveau
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16347900    2403140   13944760     280940     145180    1013036
-/+ buffers/cache:    1244924   15102976
Swap:     32226300          0   32226300
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Selected interface 'wlan0'
OK
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
stop: Unknown instance: 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.

Thu Sep 24 20:39:44 CST 2015: performing suspend
sh: echo: I/O error
Thu Sep 24 20:39:45 CST 2015: Awake.
Thu Sep 24 20:39:45 CST 2015: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
Reloaded unloaded modules.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Selected interface 'wlan0'
OK
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

Thu Sep 24 20:39:46 CST 2015: Finished.
```

**pm-powersave.log**

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false:
Setting Wake On Lan for eth0 to enable...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false:
Setting power savings for snd_hda_intel to 0...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false:
Laptop mode disabled.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false:
Setting Host Bridge 0000:00:00.0 to on
Setting Audio device 0000:00:03.0 to on
Setting Audio device 0000:00:1b.0 to on
Setting Ethernet device 0000:06:00.0 to on
Setting Wireless device 0000:07:00.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false:
sh: echo: I/O error
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false:
Setting SATA ALPM on host0 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host1 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host2 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host3 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host4 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host5 to max_performance...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false:
**sched policy powersave OFF
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false:
Setting /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-6 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false:
cat: /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/enabled: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/95hdparm-apm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/anacron false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false:
Setting Wake On Lan for eth0 to enable...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/disable_wol false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false:
Setting power savings for snd_hda_intel to 0...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false:
Laptop mode disabled.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/laptop-mode false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false:
Setting Host Bridge 0000:00:00.0 to on
Setting Audio device 0000:00:03.0 to on
Setting Audio device 0000:00:1b.0 to on
Setting Ethernet device 0000:06:00.0 to on
Setting Wireless device 0000:07:00.0 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pci_devices false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false:
sh: echo: I/O error
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/pcie_aspm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false:
Setting SATA ALPM on host0 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host1 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host2 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host3 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host4 to max_performance...Done.
Setting SATA ALPM on host5 to max_performance...Done.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sata_alpm false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false:
**sched policy powersave OFF
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/sched-powersave false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false:
Setting /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-6 to on
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false:
cat: /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/enabled: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless false: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/xfs_buffer false: not applicable.
```

---

**My question is:**

- How to check which part cause the `sh: echo: I/O error`
- What is the possible reason that make `pm-suspend` won't work?

---

*Update*

This issue still not fixed, does anyone know would mint mate 18 fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed `mint mate 18` on my laptop, the issue is fixed.

I think mint takes time to fully support new hardwares, so use new release on old hardware usually fix issue like this.